# Jquery option add url to button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the following to work, but for some reason it isn't and I just can't seem to see why. What I am trying to do is when someone selects an option in the form, it applies the download url to the button.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
          <select class="relationship" id="Relationship">
          <option>Select Form</option>
          <option>for me</option>
          <option>for another</option>
          </select>

<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary download" href="#">
<i class="icon-download"></i>     Download Form</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".relationship").change(function(){
if( $(this).val() == "for me" ) { 
$("a.download").click(function() {
location.href = 'form1.pdf'; 
})} 

else if ($(this).val() == "for another") {
$("a.download").click(function() {
location.href = 'form2.pdf';
})}
}); 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the download href dynamically instead using [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
$(function(){
    $(".relationship").on('change', function(){
        if( $(this).val() == "for me" ) { 
            $("a.download").attr('href', 'form1.pdf');  
        }

        else if ($(this).val() == "for another") {
            $("a.download").attr('href', 'form2.pdf');  
        }
    });
});
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/kLDTm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.download').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = ($('.relationship').val() == 'for me') ? 'form1.pdf' : 'form2.pdf';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must cpecify `option`s value in the `select` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/kNyjf/):

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <select class="relationship" id="Relationship" onchange="$('.download').attr('href', $(this).val());">
    <option value='#'>Select Form</option>
    <option value="http://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/15.0.1147.153/win/Opera_15.0.1147.153_Setup.exe">Opera</option>
    <option value="https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/22.0/win32/ru/Firefox%20Setup%20Stub%2022.0.exe">Firefox</option>
  </select>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary download" href="#">
      <i class="icon-download"></i>Download Form
  </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works Your problem is somewhere else make sure you include the jquery before the script or you have the download files there.